# Why do I have a `/root/.rpmdb` folder on a Debian-based distro?

Tags: debian, rpm, deb, devuan

I just noticed my Devuan ASCII machine has a `/root/.rpmdb` folder.

Why would it have been created, seeing how I use apt DEB files, not RPMs? And - how safe is it to delete it?

Comment: Not a definitive answer as to *what* created the directory, but there's possible candidates  https://askubuntu.com/a/476941/295286

Comment: Maybe you find this helpful https://askubuntu.com/a/476941

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/476941/295286) provided by @SergiyKolodyazhnyy :

If you've used a stand-alone installer for some third-party kernel module in the [DKMS framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) - DKMS module installers support multiple distros, including those based on rpm. Apparently the installer tries to query your distro's RPM database (which IMHO it shouldn't), and the result of this scan is the silent creation of a `$HOME/.rpmdb` directory if one does not already exist for the current user. ... and the current user happens to be root when you're installing kernel modules.

Examples of such module packages: VirtualBox, NVIDIA GPUs, ndiswrapper, openswan.